# Mediawiki should react to dynamic created content

Tags: php, html, mediawiki

I have an extension that dynamically creates content for some pages.

E.g. I have creates headlines with the `<html> <h1>, <h2> and <h3>`.
I want my mediawiki to react to the headline tags to create a directory dynamically.

I already tried using == in the specific tags in my extension, but mediawiki simply creates the string which will be displayed.

How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hooking to [`ParserFirstCallInit`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ParserFirstCallInit)?

You may need to parse the wikitext that you're returning, before returning it. Use something like `$out = $parser->recursiveTagParse( "== Wikitext here ==" );`

Alternatively, if you just want to return raw HTML, you can return an array of the form `[ 0 => $outputHtml, 'isHTML' => true ]`.

I'm not sure what you mean by "create a directory dynamically" but if you're just trying to create HTML in a wikipage then the above should work.

Comment: You can create headlines in Wiki with "== HEADLINE ==". With that headlines you can create a directory. E.g. I create some tables with an extension with a specific headlines for each table. Those headlines should be interpreted by the wiki.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean: a directory of *topics*... I was thinking a filesystem directory. Does recursiveTagParse work?